# where is the clause ambiguous

Tags: mysql, sql

use dallasfood;

```
select estab_id 
from estab as EST    
left join inspect as INSP
       on EST.estab_id = INSP.estab_id    
where inspdate = '8-3-17'
  and estab_id = '2473'
```

trying to find how to fix the clause ambiguous result for estab_id. I'm trying to find the violations returned on a certain establishment for a date and can not figure out why it is ambiguous

Answer (score 2):

use table alis name in selection, as `estab_id` column in both tables that's why it shows ambigious in your query

```
select EST.estab_id 
from estab as EST    
left join inspect as INSP
on EST.estab_id = INSP.estab_id    
where inspdate = '8-3-17'
and EST.estab_id = '2473'
```

Comment: it would also be good practice (albeit not required) to give an identifier to `inspdate ` as well

Answer (score 1):

You should qualify *all* columns in your queries, particularly if there is more than one table.

The best alias is generally the shortest -- abbreviations for the table name.  Also, you should use standard date formats, assuming your date is stored as a date.

So, something like this:

```
select e.estab_id 
from estab e left join 
     inspect i
     on e.estab_id = i.estab_id and i.inspdate = '2017-08-03'
where e.estab_id = 2473;
```

Some other notes:

- I removed the single quotes around `2473`.  If `estab_id` is indeed a string, then include the single quotes.  If it is a number, then that is a bad idea, because you are mixing data types.
- I assume that `inspdate` comes from `inspect`, so it is qualified with `i`.
- Conditions on the second table in a `left join` generally go in the `on` clause.  Otherwise the join is turned into an inner join.